# Java client-server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server

This problem is bugging me for over a day now and I cannot find a fix for it.I am writing a chat application in Java.The problem is that the server cannot send messages to the clients,but can only receive it.Here are my classes:

Server class:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
static InetAddress address;
static ArrayList<Integer> clients=new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Socket> socs=new ArrayList<>();
static String message="";
static DataOutputStream toClient;
static  ServerSocket socket;
static Socket socketNew;
static boolean running=false;
public Server(InetAddress address){
    this.address=address;

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    socket=new ServerSocket(8000);
    System.out.println("Server started on port 8000");
    running=true;

    while(true)
    {   
        socketNew=socket.accept();
        socs.add(socketNew);
        address=socketNew.getInetAddress();

        System.out.println("connected to client at address: "+address);

        Server server=new Server(address);
        new Thread(server).start();


    }
}


public void run() {

    {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketNew.getInputStream()));
        String message=br.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);
        for(Socket s:socs)      //sending the above msg. to all clients
        {
            OutputStream os=os = s.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
            pw.write(message);
            pw.flush();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    }
private void message() {


}       


}
```

Here is my client class' relevant functions:

```
private void receive_data()
    {
        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String message=br.readLine();
            console(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
private void send_data() {

    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
        pw.println(this.name+": "+textField.getText());
        pw.flush();
        textField.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}
```

Also,the server stop taking any messages from the client after the very first message.I thought that problem can be eliminated by enclosing the contents of the run() method in server class inside while loop.But it is throwing exceptions that way.Any solutions to the above problem?

Comment: Yes, you need to enclose it with a loop. Please change it and include the exceptions it throws (full stack trace) in your question.

Comment: The problem with this method is when I kill the client's window, there are numerous exception,and that too an infinite no. of times.I tried something like while(running) where running is initially true.If any exception is caught,I set running equal to false.But this way,the other clients also fail to send-receive any messages to the server.And could you please help me with my first problem?Why is it that the clients cannot receive any messages from the server?

Comment: Can they receive messages from other clients?

Comment: The message flow is only from the client to the server side.

Comment: There is no loop in your `run()` method to keep it running. So you only execute it once, and the thread closes.

Comment: Even if I add the loop,I cannot send messages to the clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketNew.getInputStream()));
        String message;
        PrintWriter out;

        while ((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for (Socket s : socs) // sending the above msg. to all clients
            {
                out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println(message);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There you go. Tested it with a small client i quickly wrote myself and it works.

And you definitely should work on your code formatting. (mainly those scope brackets that are there for no reason.)

Comment: Thanks man.It worked.And sorry about the formatting part.The problem gave me so much headache that I just posted it without caring for indentation.